# Sum of only given index in a list with an another integer

Tags: python, list-manipulation

I want to sum the particular index in this list

```
b = [3,4,6,8,9]
b[2:4] += 100
print(b)
```

When i try to execute i get:

```
b[2:4] += 100
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The expected Output is:

```
[3,4,106,108,9]
```

Can anyone help me out to get me my expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `enumerate` and list comprehension

```
>>> b=[3,4,6,8,9]
>>> [e*100 if i in range(2,4) else e for i,e in enumerate(b)]
[3, 4, 600, 800, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

Python lists do not work like that.  Just use a loop over the indices.

```
>>> b
[3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
>>> for i in range(2, 4):
...     b[i] += 100
...     
>>> b
[3, 4, 106, 108, 9]
```

Or, use numpy arrays, which do support that syntax exactly:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b = np.array([3, 4, 6, 8, 9])
>>> b[2:4] += 100
>>> b
array([  3,   4, 106, 108,   9])
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're hoping is NumPy indexing. This, however, requires the 3rd party NumPy library:

```
import numpy as np

b = [3,4,6,8,9]
b = np.array(b)
b[2:4] += 100

print(b)

array([  3,   4, 106, 108,   9])
```

In pure Python, you can use a list comprehension. To save having to repeat indices, you can define a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) object:

```
s = slice(2, 4)
b[s] = [i+100 for i in b[s]]

print(b)

[3, 4, 106, 108, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll answer the question as to why that fails. You're taking a `slice` of your array `b`. Which translates to,

```
>>> b = [3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
>>> b[2:4]
[6, 8]
```

Then you say, `b[2:4] + 100` which is equivalent to `[6, 8] + 100` but what does that mean to Python? Do you want to append `100` to the list? Do you want to add `100` to the first element? The second?

Are you starting to see the ambiguity here? As others have pointed out, this behavior is defined for numpy arrays but not for vanilla python.

There are many solutions for this but IMO the following is the clearest solution.

```
b = [3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
for i in range(2, 4):
    b[i] += 100
```

However, the most pythonic would involve a list comprehension which you can see in other answers but IMO that seems a little advanced for you.